# How to set intellij idea's terminal's charset?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using OSX and intellij idea.When I use Intellij idea's terminal(option+F12)，i find the default charset is utf-8.Sometimes I need to use other charset.How to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a setting within IDEA to set the encoding for the terminal. IDEA is actually running a shell command and displaying it in a window. As such, setting the encoding would be shell specific. Go into Settings and go to the `Terminal` node (its under `Tools` in IDEA v14). On that settings dialog there is the "Shell path" field. If your shell supports it, you can add a switch/argument to set the encoding.

You can open a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com asking JetBrains to add a setting for encoding in the IDEA settings. I was not able to find a request for such, but here are a couple of related tickets:

- [IDEA-128332 Embedded terminal window character encoding problems](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128332)
- [IDEA-129658 Lost encoding in terminal](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129658)